# How many collators can a parachain have?

Tags: parachain, collator, network

I think this should be split into 2 questions:

1. How many total collators can a `parachain` have ?
2. How many collators can collate at the same block height ?

I suspect those number would be approximative but also are dependent of the network settings of the validators of the given network (Kusama, Polkadot) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many collators need to be set on the parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2483/how-many-collators-need-to-be-set-on-the-parachain)

Answer (score 0):

> How many total collators can a parachain have ?

There is no particular bound on how many collators can a parachain have, there is bound on how many [parachains can connect to polkadot](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-parachains#parachain-slot-acquisition). You can check [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/select-collators/) on how to add collators to your parachain, there are different implementations for the same, for example moonbeam has a `DPoS` as its collator selection mechanism.

> How many collators can collate at the same block height ?

It again depends on the collator selection mechanism, means which collator is selected to collate at a time.

Comment: Thank you @Shubham.
I don't think your answer is accurate. There are technical limit to the number of collators that can collate at the same block height like for example the fact validators have limited resources (number of connections, bandwidth,...). 
This was the case when cumulus didn't have a consensus and all collators were trying to produce the same block, which failed with a high number of collators because the validators part of the core group couldn't download all the blocks nor accept all the connections at the same time.